# Cause for crash in std::set::insert

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am trying to debug a problem where our program crashes (segfault) in the ´addToOurSet` method below:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ( ... )
    void addToOurSet(SomeOtherClass* obj) { ourSet.insert(obj); }
    std::set<SomeOtherClass*> ourSet;
};
```

The crash is hard to reproduce due to (among other things, the complexity and large data size involved, and failure to reproduce in a debug build; the above example is obviously highly simplified). The traceback shows the crash occurring in:

```
std::_Rb_tree<...>::insert_unique(SomeOtherClass* const&)
```

My question is: What could cause the `ourSet.insert(...)` method to crash? As far as I understand, there is nothing with the inserted object itself that could cause it, since it is a pointer. Correct? So am I looking at a problem with the set itself? Obviously, if the set pointer is invalid for some reason, the call could crash, but could for example some operation on the set cause it to be invalid in this way (like for example deleting past its end or something that is forbidden)?

Comment: The root cause is likely memory corruption at a different place in yoru program which is showing up in the `insert` method.  Have you tried running your program under valgrind or a similar tool?  It will hopefully point out the problem

Comment: stack smash is one possibility.

Comment: I suspect memory corruption as well, but my question is if I should be focus on possible invalidation of the set itself (such as deleting the SomeClass instance), or if, for example, an invalid operation on the set could cause this.

Comment: @Krumelur: Focus on what the others already identified. Indeed nothing in the inner workings of the `std::set` should be dereferencing your pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. The `set` itself is invalid (the enclosing `SomeClass` instance has been deleted, or is being accessed through a dangling pointer etc).
2. There's a memory corruption somewhere.

I'd probably start with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) or a similar tool.

Comment: Your points are very valid, but unfortunately running valgrind is not possible due to the complexity of the program (I already tried and failed...).

Comment: @Krumelur: (a) that makes no sense (b) why are you not debugging with a stripped-down version of your program? (c) this _is_ **the** answer. Good luck.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I couldn't agree more. I was merely hoping to narrow down the search a bit.

Comment: @Krumelur: Please do that _before_ posting, not after ;)

Comment: ...narrow it down hoping this was the result of a common error and easily recognized by someone on SO...

Answer (score 1):

I ran across a similar problem recently. It turned out that I had 2 slightly different declarations for the same class. In foo.h:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ( ... )
    void addToOurSet(SomeOtherClass* obj) { ourSet.insert(obj); }
    std::set<SomeOtherClass*> ourSet;
};
```

and in bar.h:

```
class SomeClass {
    // ( ... )
    std::vector<SomeOtherClass*> ourSet;
};
```

It compiled fine but segfaulted deep in <set>.